# Is there a way to use a Scanner to build a set of objects from reading a file?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I was wondering if there was a way to have a scanner read through a file in java and compile it into an object of an arraylist, for example if the file being read is in the same basic format of a workers attributes in the file being; Name, Payrate(float), skills 1(float), skills 2(float), then have it repeat again after a new worker is introduced. Such as;

file "workers.txt":

Bob Overflow
Full-time 12.50 phr
Painting .45
carving  .85

Susan Nasus
part-time 7.50 phr
painting .80
carving .25

then compile it to be worker 1, worker 2, worker 3 ect with the given attributes into an array.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RaceCarOne
{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
            //creating File instance to reference text file in Java
            File text = new File("C:\\Users\\jayli\\Desktop\\Workers.txt");
            //Creating Scanner instance to read File in Java
            Scanner s = new Scanner(text);
            //Reading each line of file using Scanner class
            int lineNumber = 1;
            while(s.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + line);
                lineNumber++;
            }          
            s.close();  
        }   
}

class Worker 
{
    File text = new File("C:\\Users\\jayli\\Desktop\\Workers.txt");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(text);

    String Name;
    int WorkHours;
    int Fab;
    int Serv;
    int Diag;
    int Trans;
    int Intake;
    int BW;
    int Paint;
    boolean working = false;

    Worker(String workername, float pay, float Fab, float Serv, float Diag, float Trans, float Intake, float BW, float Paint)
    {
        while(s.hasNextLine())
        {

        workername = s.nextLine();
        pay = s.nextInt();
        Fab = s.nextInt();
        Serv = s.nextInt();
        Diag = s.nextInt();
        Trans = s.nextInt();
        Intake = s.nextInt();
        BW = s.nextInt();
        Paint = s.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably be better off if you could store the info in a standard format like JSON, then you can just use a JSON parser to parse it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You can initialize Scanner inside the constructor in the class Worker. make the constructor throw FileNotFoundException

Comment: The answer is “yes”, but as it stands your question is too broad to be suitable for this site. Please narrow your question to a specific problem with part of your code. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm unsure how to break the file up into multiple "worker" objects and put them into an array. The file I'm reading in is in the same format for all the workers, with name, then pay, fabrication, servicing, ect ect. and then it moves onto the next name, and so on. I need help with figuring out how to build an object based off of just one set of those attributes. So that I can compile all the workers into an array list.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the s.nextline() to get a line, and then split it according to your wishes. You could use a regex pattern for this which you can test with [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) for example. Alternatively you can use the [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)-Method and split by spaces. However, as this invokes other problems (e.g. skills with spaces in their name), I agree with Sweeper in that you should probably use something like JSON for your input.

Additionally, I think your constructor for Worker just loops through the whole file and you end up with the info on the last line everytime.